# LLVM missing linker and can't compile the lld (llvm linker)

Tags: linker, llvm, linker-errors, lld

I want to build a compiler to a new target and I choose llvm. As far as I understand, I can use the clang project as a front end and llvm as a back end. I can get .o files out of the llc (part of the llvm). now I need to link them all into executable. I tried using lld project but it failed compiling with the error :

```
Desktop/llvm_project/llvm/lib/Target/ARM/ARMISelLowering.cpp: In member function ‘llvm::Instruction* llvm::ARMTargetLowering::makeDMB(llvm::IRBuilder<>&, llvm::ARM_MB::MemBOpt) const’:
Desktop/llvm_project/llvm/lib/Target/ARM/ARMISelLowering.cpp:11000:73: error: could not convert ‘{(& Builder)->llvm::IRBuilder<>::<anonymous>.llvm::IRBuilderBase::getInt32(15u), (& Builder)->llvm::IRBuilder<>::<anonymous>.llvm::IRBuilderBase::getInt32(0u), (& Builder)->llvm::IRBuilder<>::<anonymous>.llvm::IRBuilderBase::getInt32(0u), (& Builder)->llvm::IRBuilder<>::<anonymous>.llvm::IRBuilderBase::getInt32(7u), (& Builder)->llvm::IRBuilder<>::<anonymous>.llvm::IRBuilderBase::getInt32(10u), (& Builder)->llvm::IRBuilder<>::<anonymous>.llvm::IRBuilderBase::getInt32(5u)}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>’
                                Builder.getInt32(10), Builder.getInt32(5)};
                                                                         ^
make[2]: *** [lib/Target/ARM/CMakeFiles/LLVMARMCodeGen.dir/ARMISelLowering.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [lib/Target/ARM/CMakeFiles/LLVMARMCodeGen.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

so I have several question cause I think I am missing something :

1. if I don't have binutils for the new target, how should I use the llvm project ? - they create they great project...but without the final piece that actually create running files ?! what should I use as a linker ?
2. anyone encountered this lld build error and solved it ?

uname -a

- Linux my_name-Inspiron-3521 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug
  15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc -v

- Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=gcc
  COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
  Target: x86_64-linux-gnu Configured with: ../src/configure -v
  --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu Thread model: posix gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering is in llvm itself, not lld. I'm not seeing that error on the [buildbots](http://lab.llvm.org:8011/console), so I recommend updating your source tree.

As for binutils, llvm does not currently provide a complete replacement for them. This is being worked on, but it will be a while before it's completed. For now I recommend using gnu binutils with either ld or gold as the linker.

Comment: if I build llvm without the ld project it works. when adding ld project I get the above error.